# CI/CD Gitlab. SDK location not found

Tags: android, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-runner

Происходит при запуске на сайте, не на локальном сервере.
Где расположение ANDROID_HOME?

> SDK location not found. Define location with sdk.dir in the local.properties file or with an ANDROID_HOME environment variable.

**gitlab-ci.yml**

```
image: openjdk:8-jdk

variables:
  ANDROID_COMPILE_SDK: "26"
  ANDROID_BUILD_TOOLS: "26.0.1"

before_script:
  - apt-get --quiet update --yes
  - apt-get --quiet install --yes wget tar unzip lib32stdc++6 lib32z1
  - wget --quiet --output-document=android-sdk.zip https://dl.google.com/android/repository/tools_r${ANDROID_SDK_TOOLS}-linux.zip
  - unzip android-sdk.zip
  - export ANDROID_HOME=$PWD/
  - echo y | $ANDROID_HOME/tools/android --silent update sdk --no-ui --all --filter android-${ANDROID_COMPILE_SDK}
  - echo y | $ANDROID_HOME/tools/android --silent update sdk --no-ui --all --filter platform-tools
  - echo y | $ANDROID_HOME/tools/android --silent update sdk --no-ui --all --filter build-tools-${ANDROID_BUILD_TOOLS}
  - echo y | $ANDROID_HOME/tools/android --silent update sdk --no-ui --all --filter extra-android-m2repository
  - echo y | $ANDROID_HOME/tools/android --silent update sdk --no-ui --all --filter extra-google-google_play_services
  - echo y | $ANDROID_HOME/tools/android --silent update sdk --no-ui --all --filter extra-google-m2repository
  - export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME
  - chmod +x ./gradlew

stages:
  - build

build:
  stage: build
  script:
    - ./gradlew assembleDebug
  artifacts:
    paths:
    - app/build/outputs/
```

Comment: Команда `export ANDROID_HOME=$PWD/` устанавливает `ANDROID_HOME` в текущую директорию — куда вы распаковываете `android-sdk.zip`. Попробуйте проделать всё то же самое на локальной машине: скачайте и распакуйте архив, выполните `export ANDROID_HOME=$PWD/`, попробуйте запустить сборку.

Comment: Кстати, вместо `echo y |` можно `yes | `

Comment: Подсмотрите как сделано в примере: https://about.gitlab.com/2016/11/30/setting-up-gitlab-ci-for-android-projects

Comment: @woesss вроде бы оттуда код и взят.

Comment: Что с этим вопросом, получилось решить?

Comment: @nick-volynkin, импортировал проект с github, сгенерировал средствами gitlab gitlab-ci.yml(Создать новый файл в нужной ветке -> выбрал тип файла gitlab-ci.yml -> Android) и проблема решена...теперь проблема с "ConstraintLayout for Android 1.0.2, Solver for ConstraintLayout 1.0.2" там же. Вопрос создан по теме.

Comment: UPDATE: в репозитории не должно быть файла local.properties, потому что параметр sdk.dir в нем имеет приоритет над $ANDROID_HOME для Gradle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UPDATE: в репозитории не должно быть файла local.properties, потому что параметр sdk.dir в нем имеет приоритет над $ANDROID_HOME для Gradle. (с) DeKaNszn

Сервер пытался найти SDK используя путь, который указан в **local.properties**. В **local.properties** лежит путь локальной машины, а не путь до SDK на сервере.